# Google Cloud SQL shared or individual database user accounts when using cloud-sql-proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

Since the cloud-sql-proxy already forces individual user authentication with the database through a users iam account, and allows specifying read / write permissions, it seems potentially pointless to also have an individual database accounts for each user as well.

For security, is it necessary to have a database user per dev when using cloud-sql-proxy, or is it fine to just have one database user, since they are already authenticated by the time they can enter a database user / password anyways. I'm not a server dev or a DBA, so I thought it best to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you have 2 levels of permissions

- Cloud IAM allows you to access to Cloud SQL product or not
- Database user management allows to log into the db engine and to get the db engine permission (access to a specific schema, one schema per developer, on the same SQL instance for instance).

The hosted database engine are based on MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQL Server. All those databases have their legacy user authentication in place. You have to deal with.